# Proof Regarding Relative Primality

Tags: prime-numbers, gcd-and-lcm

I have been trying to prove this fact, but I am still stuck. How can I prove that $n^2 - n + 1$ and $n^2 + n - 1$ are relatively prime for any integer $n$? In other words, that their $gcd$ is $1$. My approach so far is to assume that there exists a divisor $> 1$ and try to arrive at a contradiction, but I am failing to arrive at a contradiction. Or is there any other way to prove it?

Comment: Any number that divides them both divides their difference.

Answer (score 3):

$(n^2+n-1,n^2-n+1) = (n^2-n+1,2n-2)=(n^2-n+1,n-1) = (n-1,1)=1$

$(n^2-n+1,2n-2)=(n^2-n+1,n-1)$ because $2 \not| n^2-n+1$ since its always odd number.

Edit : to prove that $ n^2-n+1$ is always odd once substitute for $n=2k$ even integers and once $n=2k+1$ odd integers and show in every case the result we get is odd.

Comment: well you have to show that $n^2-n+1$ is odd number for complete answer. Also you have to mention how did you get $2n-2$ (eg., subtracting both).

Comment: Also, $n^2-n=n(n-1)$, i.e., the product of consecutive integers, so it must be even.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) applied to polynomials we find that:
$$(n+2)(n^2−n+1) - n(n^2+n−1) = 2$$

Any common factor of $n^2−n+1$ and $n^2+n−1$ divides the left hand side, so also divides $2$. It cannot actually be $2$ because $n^2+n−1 = n(n+1)−1$ is always odd (one of $n$ or $n+1$ must be even). Therefore the only possible common factor is $1$.